# DocumentPage not getting the images from the fixed XPS document page

Tags: vb.net, image-rendering, fixeddocument, documentpaginator

I have this code

```
Private Sub SaveFixDoc(ByVal fd As FixedDocument, name As String)

    Dim filename As String = My.Settings.Path2Labels & "\" & name & ".xps"

    Try
        Dim xpsd As XpsDocument = New XpsDocument(filename, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
        Dim xpsdw As XpsDocumentWriter = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsd)
        xpsdw.Write(fd) ' Write the FixedDocument as a document.

       ' ** All the way to here the fd.pages.child have my text and my images and they are rendered ok
        Dim sequence As FixedDocumentSequence = xpsd.GetFixedDocumentSequence()

        For pageCount As Integer = 0 To sequence.DocumentPaginator.PageCount - 1

            Dim page As DocumentPage = sequence.DocumentPaginator.GetPage(pageCount)

           '  **but in here the page is only taking the text and completely ignoring the images they just appear as empty paths **
            Dim toBitmap As New RenderTargetBitmap(4 * (CInt(page.Size.Width)), 4 * (CInt(page.Size.Height)), 384, 384, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Pbgra32)
            toBitmap.Render(page.Visual)

            Dim bmpEncoder As JpegBitmapEncoder = New JpegBitmapEncoder()
            bmpEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(toBitmap))

            Dim fStream As New FileStream(My.Settings.Path2Labels & "\" & name & ".jpeg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
            bmpEncoder.Save(fStream)
            fStream.Close()
        Next

        xpsd.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        Dim st As New StackTrace(True)
        st = New StackTrace(ex, True)
        Utilities.WriteToApplicationLog(New LogMessage() With {
                                           .MessageType = "Error",
                                           .MessageDetails = ex.ToString})

        Mediator.NotifyColleagues("MessageBox", New MessageBoxObject() With {
                                     .message =
                                     My.Resources.mbInstrError & " SaveSingleFixedContentDocument " & " " &
                                     st.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber().ToString,
                                     .caption = My.Resources.mbExcelError,
                                     .button = MessageBoxButton.OK,
                                     .image = MessageBoxImage.Error})
    End Try
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14l2p.png)

#### fd.page.child:

[image: fd.page.child]

#### page.visual:

[image: page.visual]

I have change the renderer to several formats, made the render async and still the images will not load. How can I fix this?

Comment: The `fStream` variable should be declared in a `Using` block.

Answer (score 0):

ok, it turns out "sequence"  was not getting all the data from the fixedDocument so I used the FixedDocument paginator instead

```
  For pageCount As Integer = 0 To fd.DocumentPaginator.PageCount - 1
                Dim page As DocumentPage = fd.DocumentPaginator.GetPage(pageCount)
```